# Class returns with only 1 item in the list rather than more

Tags: python, python-2.7

I expected to get two list that contains all males in one and all females in another list. I am just getting a list with only one item.

Using Python2.7

Output: ['Phyllis Lapin'] ['Roy Anderson']

Expected Output :['Phyllis Lapin', 'Pam Beesly', 'Angela Martin' etc..]

------------------------['Dwight Shrute','Jim Halpert','Ryan Howard' etc..]

```
class Employee:
    num_of_emps = 0

    def __init__(self, first, last, position, sex):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.position = position
        self.sex = sex
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@DunderMifflin.com'

        Employee.num_of_emps += 1

    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

    @staticmethod
    def work_today(day):
        # 0 = Monday  3 = Thursday  6 = Sunday
        if day.weekday() == 6 or day.weekday() == 3:
            return False
        return True


# MANAGER Michael

class Manager(object, Employee):
    male = []
    female = []

    def __init__(self, first, last, position, sex, employees=None):
        Employee.__init__(self, first, last, position, sex)

        if employees is None:
            self.employees = []
        else:
            self.employees = employees

        for emp in self.employees:
            if emp.sex == "M":
                self.male = [emp.fullname()]

        for emp in self.employees:
            if emp.sex == "F":
                self.female = [emp.fullname()]

    def add_emp(self, emp):
        if emp not in self.employees:
            self.employees(emp)

    def males_emps(self):
        print "_____"
        print "Male"
        print "-----"
        for emp in self.employees:
            if emp.sex == "M":
                print emp.fullname()

    def female_emps(self):
        print "______"
        print "Female"
        print "------"
        for emp in self.employees:
            if emp.sex == "F":
                print emp.fullname()

    def remove_emp(self, emp):
        if emp in self.employees:
            self.employees.remove(emp)

    def print_emp(self):
        Michael.males_emps()
        Michael.female_emps()


Dwight = Employee('Dwight', 'Schrute', 'Assistant to the Regional Manager', 'M')
Jim = Employee('Jim', 'Halpert', 'Sales Representative', 'M')
Pam = Employee('Pam', 'Beesly', 'Receptionist', 'F')
Ryan = Employee('Ryan', 'Howard', 'Temp', 'M')
Angela = Employee('Angela', 'Martin', 'Senior Accountant', 'F')
Kelly = Employee('Kelly', 'Kapoor', 'Customer Service Representative', 'F')
Toby = Employee('Toby', 'Flenderson', 'Human Resource Representative', 'M')
Creed = Employee('Creed', 'Bratton', 'Quality Assurance', 'M')
Darryl = Employee('Darryl', 'Philbin', 'Warehouse Worker', 'M')
Kevin = Employee('Kevin', 'Malone', 'Accountant', 'M')
Meredith = Employee('Meredith', 'Palmer', 'Accounting', 'F')
Oscar = Employee('Oscar', 'Martinez', 'Accountant', 'M')
Phyllis = Employee('Phyllis', 'Lapin', 'Sales Representative', 'F')
Stanley = Employee('Stanley', 'Hudson', 'Sales Representative', 'M')
Roy = Employee('Roy', 'Anderson', 'Warehouse Worker', 'M')

Michael = Manager('Michael', 'Scott', 'Regional Manager', 'M', [Dwight,
                                                                Jim,
                                                                Pam,
                                                                Ryan,
                                                                Angela,
                                                                Kelly,
                                                                Toby,
                                                                Creed,
                                                                Darryl,
                                                                Kevin,
                                                                Meredith,
                                                                Oscar,
                                                                Phyllis,
                                                                Stanley,
                                                                Roy])


print Michael.female
print Michael.male
```

can you please help thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overriding the `self.male` and `self.female` fields in each iteration, what you want to do is append the lists with the new elements

for your Manager's `__init__` try:

```
def __init__(self, first, last, position, sex, employees=None):
    Employee.__init__(self, first, last, position, sex)

    if employees is None:
        self.employees = []
    else:
        self.employees = employees

    self.male = []
    self.female = []

    for emp in self.employees:
        if emp.sex == "M":
            self.male.append(emp.fullname())

    for emp in self.employees:
        if emp.sex == "F":
            self.female.append(emp.fullname())
```

Comment: In fact, you also do not want to "declare" the `male` and `female` members in the class definition. Unlike in other OO languages, object members must not be declared in the class definition. You would want to just initialize these members in the constructor. Note that @Evyatar's code has a small issue with it, because it uses `+=` when it should have used the `append` method.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron `male` and `female` are declared in the `__init__`, so I'm not sure what you meant by "in the class definition". Also fixed the code with append, thanks!

Comment: the comment about not declaring `male` and `female` was to the original question. While your code showed that these members need to be initialized in the constructor, you did not emphasize that these members needed to be removed from the class declarations.

Comment: your'e correct, I missed the fact that he declares them in the class instead of in the `__init__`